# how to use a dynamic orderBy in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-orderby

ive been reading on how to use a dynamic orderby with a ng-repeat but i stuck. The object I am working with looks like this:

```
 {
    "type": "Active",
    "properties": {
        "id": 105935,
        "name": "Museum Hill Estates",
        "show": false,
        "territoryId": 1996
    },
    "metrics": {
        "bld": {
            "type": "Unknown",
            "count": {
                "prod": 78,
                "custom": 90
            }
        },
        "inv": {
            "fut": 9,
            "vdl": 6,
            "mod": 1,
            "fin": 3,
            "uc": 3,
            "total": 22
        },
        "loe": {
            "bld": 11,
            "inv": 20,
            "size": 3,
            "activity": 9,
            "total": 43
        }
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -105.93069,
            35.65802
        ]
    }
}
```

By default I need (desc) name,total loe, inventory(fut/vdl/mod/uc/fin/total)
I have 3 checkboxes in a btn-group i want to use for changing the order. currently only the first one in the filter is working.

here is a working plunker
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOrW2EEjX4umZv3dHd9D?p=preview)

```
 vm.sortByName = 'properties.name';
    vm.sortByLoeTotal = 'metrics.loe.total';
    vm.sortByInv = ['metrics.inv.fut','metrics.inv.vdl','metrics.inv.mod','metrics.inv.uc','metrics.inv.fin','metrics.inv.total'];

    vm.setSubdivisionSorting = function (filter) {
        if (filter === 'loe' && vm.loeFilter === true) {
            vm.sortByLoeTotal = 'metrics.loe.total';
            vm.loeFilter = false;
        }
        if (filter === 'loe' && vm.loeFilter === false) {
            vm.sortByLoeTotal = '-metrics.loe.total';
            vm.loeFilter = true;
        }
        if (filter === 'inventory' && vm.inventoryFilter === true) {
           vm.sortByInv = ['metrics.inv.fut', 'metrics.inv.vdl', 'metrics.inv.mod', 'metrics.inv.uc', 'metrics.inv.fin', 'metrics.inv.total'];
           vm.inventoryFilter = false;
        }
        if (filter === 'inventory' && vm.inventoryFilter === false) {
           vm.sortByInv = ['-metrics.inv.fut', '-metrics.inv.vdl', '-metrics.inv.mod', '-metrics.inv.uc', '-metrics.inv.fin', '-metrics.inv.total'];
           vm.inventoryFilter = true;
        }
        if (filter === 'subdivision' && vm.subdivisionFilter === true) {
            vm.sortByName = 'properties.name';
            vm.subdivisionFilter = false;
        }
        if (filter === 'subdivision' && vm.subdivisionFilter === false) {
            vm.sortByName = '-properties.name';
            vm.subdivisionFilter = true;
        }
    };
```

i just found a angular-filter module and included it in the punker in case someone believes that is a way to go.

Comment: hope someone answers this. I have something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C5ZYQE10509habk531Pd?p=preview). I've modified/cleaned the code quite abit so it's easier to read.

The arguments to the `orderBy` filter are prioritised from left to right. Which means that even if you specify multiple properties to order on and the target value of the first property are not the same, the second property is not used in sorting.

```
var orderBy = ['name', 'age'];

var data = [{
 name: 'Foo',
 age: 102
}, {
 name: 'Bar',
 age: 99999 // <-- not used in sorting since the name property differs
}];
```

Simply don't include the fields in the `orderBy` that you don't want to use to sort on; don't include them as a descending sort.

Also, you might want to take a look into something like `$scope.$watch` instead of applying `ng-change` on html elements. Keep your model state in the controller en let the view adjust to it.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: i am having some issues integrating it with my project. if i create another question can u take a look

Comment: @texas697 sure, I might have some time tomorrow night

Comment: well i actually just made the post! thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386458/angular-watchgroup-not-consistently-picking-up-model-changes

Comment: ok, i figured out what was wrong. I had to initialize it with         vm.orderBy = ['properties.name', 'metrics.loe.total', 'metrics.inv.fut', 'metrics.inv.vdl', 'metrics.inv.mod', 'metrics.inv.uc', 'metrics.inv.fin', 'metrics.inv.total'];

Comment: also i got another question if you have time to look at it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419370/how-to-include-a-string-includes-function-inside-a-angular-filter   thanks!