# how to include a "string includes" function inside a angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am working on filtering with checkboxes, My geojson has a property of status. the status is value looks like this:

> status
>   :
>   "Act 3Q99"

or

> status
>   :
>   "Fut 3Q99"

I need to filter by "Act" or "Fut". here is my filter:

```
   function StatusFilter() {

    return function (territorySubdivisions, typeFilter) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(territorySubdivisions, function (subdivision) {
            if (typeFilter.active == true && typeFilter.future == true) {
                filtered.push(subdivision);
            }
            else if (typeFilter.active == true && typeFilter.future == false && subdivision.properties.status == subdivision.properties.status.indexOf('Act') != -1) {
                filtered.push(subdivision);
            }
            else if (typeFilter.future == true && typeFilter.active == false && subdivision.properties.status == subdivision.properties.status.indexOf('Fut') != -1) {
                filtered.push(subdivision);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
};
```

here is what I tried.

> subdivision.properties.status.indexOf('Act') != -1

It of course is not working. I created a working plunker. I included other orderBy and filtering code to make sure there were no conflicts.

[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OnUryDqiRYrhoDjIj5z8?p=preview)

```
   <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="active-checkbox-filter" ng-model="vm.typeFilter.active" ng-change="vm.statusActive('active')">
                <label for="active-checkbox-filter"> Active </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="future-checkbox-filter" ng-model="vm.typeFilter.future" ng-change="vm.statusFuture('future')">
                <label for="future-checkbox-filter"> Future </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks strange. Don't you just need this:

```
if (typeFilter.active === true && typeFilter.future === true) {
    filtered.push(subdivision);
} else if (typeFilter.active === true && typeFilter.future === false && subdivision.properties.status.indexOf('Act') >= 0) {
    filtered.push(subdivision);
} else if (typeFilter.future === true && typeFilter.active === false && subdivision.properties.status.indexOf('Fut') >= 0) {
    filtered.push(subdivision);
}
```

?

Comment: looks like that is it

Comment: I would also change those comparisons with boolean values to `booleanVariable` and `!booleanVariable`.

Comment: can u adjust the plunker please. thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Here's some refactoring of @Mate's answer, primarily to adhere to the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle:

```
var active = typeFilter.active;
var future = typeFilter.future;
var status = subdivision.properties.status;

var match = (active && future) ||
            (active && !future && status.indexOf('Act') >= 0) ||
            (future && !active && status.indexOf('Fut') >= 0);

if (match) {
    filter.push(subdivision);
}
```

Note that once you have the boolean `match` answer you could just use `Array.filter` instead to produce your result instead of accumulating the results with `.push` - it's supported on MSIE 9+, so it'll work on any browser that AngularJS supports, reducing your code above to:

```
function StatusFilter() {
    return function (territorySubdivisions, typeFilter) {
        return territorySubdivisions.filter(function(subdivision) {
            var active = typeFilter.active;
            var future = typeFilter.future;
            var status = subdivision.properties.status;

           return (active && future) ||
                  (active && !future && status.indexOf('Act') >= 0) ||
                  (future && !active && status.indexOf('Fut') >= 0);          
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: Once you have an expression that yields a Boolean, you no longer need to use the syntax that returns an array from the filter. The Boolean return is much cleaner--more similar to what Array.filter() does.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I was just about to add a note about that myself, having checked whether `Array.filter` has the same browser support as AngularJS itself (albeit not using Angular's own filter functionality)

Comment: The advantage of using an AngularJS filter is that you can use it on the View side. You can also use it on the code side, but it can be a pain figuring out how to get hold of it and what syntax to use.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship true - I've been doing some AngularJS coding recently but didn't get into filters yet.

Comment: Thanks. As I said I had just changed necessary thing and left refactor for the author :)